# Node.js --experimental-vm-modules command line option vs "type": "module" in package.json

Tags: node.js, jestjs, babeljs, es6-modules

I'm currently rewriting a NodeJS project from a messy combination of CommonJS and Babel-transpiled ES Modules to be completely ES Module based.

In the process, I've become a bit confused by how Node handles these things. I've tried to read up on it, but I seem to be missing one final piece in my understanding.

I was assuming I would no longer need to use Babel to transpile the ES Modules. This seems to be correct. However, when I run my (Jest) tests, I still need to use the --experimental-vm-modules Node flag to make everything work.

My question is: what does that flag do? Reading the documentation, this seems to enable ES Modules, but didn't I already enable ES Modules by specifying "type": "module" in the package.json file?

Relevant links:

- https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#enabling
- https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#--experimental-vm-modules
- https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules

Comment: Seems Jest's ESM support is not that stable (very new), I have tried TS + ESM + Jest setup recently, but ouldn't get Jest working in anyway. +1

Comment: Maybe that's the problem. I wonder if other test frameworks handle this better. I feel the entire CommonJS/ESM thing is confusing to a lot of people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specifying type: "module" in package.json just telling library authors your source code is based on ESM.

For jest, you need to use experimental-vm-modules because the node api jest uses to enable ESM support is still not stable as of node 18.x

https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules

Comment: The way I understand it, as soon as I put module on the package, Node knows all my code are ES modules, however, why doesn't that happen when Jest runs my code? It appears Jest needs that API to explicitly enable the support, I'm just not sure why it needs to enable it if it is already in the package.json

Comment: Jest is not fully ESM yet and uses the new ESM VM as a sandbox to run your ESM code, normally jest transpire your code to commonjs before running the tests

Comment: Ok, I think the interesting stuff is in the github issue linked from that page: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9430 Jest uses something called the 'vm' API to run tests in a sandbox. And that's the API that still has some experimental parts relating to ES modules (edit: I typed this comment in parallel with @ZEE so it contains some duplicate info)

Comment: I'm using node `v20.11.0` and still need to use the flag. if not I receive the error `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`. Do you know why?